# Why keep Doubling these number instaces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

[image]

(Not english speaker, Sorry for clumsiness)
Trying to make dice.
(reference from this video https://youtu.be/qhZWQDDKB_Y?si=3-jKHpYAqSnjX1MY)

When I make instancing texts as a real instance,
It makes duplicated instance.

How to make only single instance for singling text?

Comment: Hi. Did you see this comment by the maker of that video? "NOTE: As of Blender 3.0, the Instancing features used here are broken/deprecated-- very likely due to the introduction of Geometry Nodes and how instancing is handled "behind the scenes".  You'll want to use a version of Blender prior to 3.0 in order to use this particular method." Could that be why you are having a problem with what you want to do?

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/